# Dealing with cannot find symbol error java

Tags: java, methods, split

This is my code meant to read a file that has multiple lines, each containing strings and floats and print out each line. I keep getting an error cannot find symbol for the method split() and loadStrings().
What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import  java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.SplittableRandom;
 public class EmployeePay {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException  {
    if (args.length != 1) {  
        final String msg = "Usage: EmployeePay name_of_input file";
          System.err.println(msg);
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(msg);
           }

      final String inputFileName = args[0];
      final File input = new File (inputFileName); 
      final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input);

        String line = " ";
        String Identification = " ";
        float WorkTime;
        float MoneyPerHour;
        int TotalDeductions= 0;
        String[] lines, info;
        float[] numberInfo;
          lines = loadStrings(scanner);
          info = new String [lines.length];
          numberInfo = new float [lines.length];
          String [] tokens;
          for (int i =0; i < lines.length; i++){
            tokens = split(lines[i]," ");
            info [i] = tokens[0];
            numberInfo[i]= Float.parseFloat(tokens[1]);
            System.out.println(info[i]+" "+numberInfo[i]);
          }
```

Comment: Where is `split` defined? There is no such method in your `EmployeePay` class

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is right, you used 2 methods not declared. I think, you wanted to use [`String.split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) but did not know the syntax. On the other hand, you did not provide source for your `loadStrings()` method, so it might be just out of context, EG declared it non static, and tried to use it from `static main()`...

Anyway, modified your code a bit, so try something like this:

```
public static void main( final String[] args ) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    if ( args.length != 1 )
    {
        final String msg = "Usage: EmployeePay <name_of_input file>";
        System.err.println( msg );
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( msg );
    }

    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File( args[0] ) );

    final String[] lines = loadStrings( scanner );
    final String[] info = new String[lines.length];
    final float[] numberInfo = new float[lines.length];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < lines.length ; i++ )
    {
        final String[] tokens = lines[i].split( " " );
        info[i] = tokens[0];
        numberInfo[i] = Float.parseFloat( tokens[1] );
        System.out.println( info[i] + " " + numberInfo[i] );
    }
}

private static String[] loadStrings( final Scanner scanner )
{
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() )
    {
        result.add( scanner.nextLine() );
    }
    return result.toArray( new String[result.size()] );
}
```